# How to interpolate 3d points by b-spline curve in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, bspline

I´m looking for a way to interpolate 3d points with a b-spline curve using matlab. So more or less spapi with x,y,z. Is there something matlab built-in?

Comment: `interp3` for example

Comment: Do you need a b-spline specifically or would something like `cscvn` work? For example [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/examples/constructing-spline-curves-in-2d-and-3d.html)

Comment: I do not have a grid of points. I want to interpolate a 3d-curve. `interp3` only takes gridded data. And it has to be b-spline.

Comment: well if you have the individual variable `x` and `y` you can create a gridded data with [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html).